# Python || Not able to convert my for loop o/p into a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, conditional-statements

If I am running a for loop on a column of a data frame. I am getting the output but it is just lists of numbers.  How can I create that list into a data frame and add it to the original data frame so that I can compute other operations on that column?

```
for i in df['discounted_price']:
    if i > 600:
        net_revenue = 25 * i / 100
        print(net_revenue)
    elif (i > 350) and (i <= 600):
        net_revenue = 15 * i / 100
        print(net_revenue)
    elif (i > 100) and (i <= 350):
        net_revenue = 10 * i / 100
        print(net_revenue)
    elif i <= 100:
        net_revenue = 5 * i / 100
        print(net_revenue)
```

Comment: Hi, @saurav. Could you please add some code snippet to your question?

Comment: Hey, buddy! You need to present codes, examples, better explanation, so on! Formulate better what you need, then, I think you could get some help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: for i in df['discounted_price']:
    if i >600:
        net_revenue = 25*i/100
        print(net_revenue)
    elif (i>350) and (i<=600):
        net_revenue= 15*i/100
        print(net_revenue)
    elif (i>100) and (i<=350):
        net_revenue = 10*i/100
        print(net_revenue)
    elif (i<=100):
        net_revenue = 5*i/100
        print(net_revenue)

Comment: Clarifying code should be added to your question, not the comments.

Comment: maybe you should add valeus on list and later replace assing new values to this column, OR you could use `.apply()` to run function with your code - and it would have to use `return` instead of `print()`

Answer (score 0):

Preparation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'discounted_price': rng.integers(10,100, 10)*10
})
df
###
   discounted_price
0               180
1               790
2               680
3               490
4               480
5               870
6               170
7               720
8               280
9               180
```

Conditional manipulation based on values:

```
condlist = [df['discounted_price'] > 600, df['discounted_price'] > 350, df['discounted_price'] > 100, df['discounted_price'] <= 100]
choicelist = [df['discounted_price'] * 0.25, df['discounted_price'] * 0.15, df['discounted_price'] * 0.1, df['discounted_price'] * 0.05]
df['output'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
df
###
   discounted_price  output
0               180    18.0
1               790   197.5
2               680   170.0
3               490    73.5
4               480    72.0
5               870   217.5
6               170    17.0
7               720   180.0
8               280    28.0
9               180    18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets create a dataframe out of a dictionary as example:

```
# Dictionary with list object in values
details = { 'Name' : ['Juan', 'Domingo', 'Eva', 'Maria'],
            'Age' : [33, 21, 22, 19],
            'University' : ['UNLP', 'UBA', 'UNC', 'UNR'] }
  
# creating a Dataframe object 
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

### Solution #1

Now lets do your loop:

```
filtered_age = []
for age in df["Age"]:
    if age <= 22:
        filtered_age.append(age)
```

You can then use your new list ("filtered_age") to create a new dictonary and finally a new dataframe:

```
filtered_details = {'Filtered age' : filtered_age}
df_age = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
```

|  | Filtered age |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 21 |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 19 |

### Solution #2

You can also use apply to create a True/False filter like this:

```
age_filter = df['Age'].apply(lambda x: True if x < 22 else False)
df[age_filter]
```

|  | Name | Age | University |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Domingo | 21 | UBA |
| 2 | Eva | 22 | UNC |
| 3 | Maria | 19 | UNR |